# Question regarding the output probability of a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-circuit, probability

Consider a quantum circuit $\text{Q}$, run on $|0^{n}\rangle$. For a specific $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, let's say we are interested in the probability

$$p_x = |\langle x|~\text{Q}~|0^{n}\rangle|^{2}.$$

Now, consider the set $$S=\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}.$$

Partition the set into $A$ and $\bar{A}$ such that $A \cup \bar{A} = S$ and $A\cap\bar{A}=\emptyset$ .

---

What is a proof that $p_x$ can be written as

$$p_x = \sum_{a} c_{x_A}^{a} c_{x_\overline{A}}^{a},$$

for some choices of complex numbers $\{  c_{x_A}^{a} \}$ and $\{  c_{x_\bar{A}}^{a}\}?$

---

I got this decomposition on page 6 (in the proof of Theorem 1) of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.00716.pdf) paper.

According to the paper, $x_A$ is the value of $x$ when restricted to the set $A$.

Here's what I have tried.
Note that if the output qubits labelled by regions $A$ and $\bar{A}$ are not connected by any entangling gates, the fact that such a decomposition exists is trivial. I presume the summation indicates that, in general, there will be entangling gates. But, I am not sure how that implies a sum of products. Maybe something to do with a path integral approach?

Comment: What is the question you are asking? Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You have four different subscripts/superscripts in the same equation that you aren't explaining. What is c? what is a? What is x? What is `a` being summed over? How is c related to your choice of subsets? Is the choice of subsets allowed to vary based on x? There's not enough information here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}_A$ denote the Hilbert space of qubits in partition $A$ and similarly for $\mathcal{H}_\bar{A}$. Define the operator $P:=Q|0^n\rangle\langle 0^n|Q^\dagger$ and write its Schmidt decomposition

$$
P = \sum_a R_a\otimes Q_a\tag1
$$

where $R_a$ are operators on $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $Q_a$ are operators on $\mathcal{H}_\bar{A}$. See for example the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/661808/6004) for more details about Schmidt decomposition for operators.

Finally, write

$$
\begin{align}
p_x&=|\langle x|Q|0^n\rangle|^2\tag2 \\
&= \langle x|Q|0^n\rangle\langle 0^n|Q^\dagger|x\rangle\tag3 \\
&= \langle x|P|x\rangle\tag4 \\
&= \langle x_A|\otimes\langle x_\bar{A}|\left(\sum_a R_a\otimes Q_a\right)|x_A\rangle\otimes|x_\bar{A}\rangle\tag5 \\
&= \sum_a \langle x_A|R_a|x_A\rangle\langle x_\bar{A}|Q_a|x_\bar{A}\rangle\tag6 \\
&= \sum_a c_{x_A}^a c_{x_\bar{A}}^a\tag7
\end{align}
$$

where we defined $c_{x_A}^a:=\langle x_A|R_a|x_A\rangle$ and $c_{x_\bar{A}}^a:=\langle x_\bar{A}|Q_a|x_\bar{A}\rangle$.

The fact that $a$ ranges over the Schmidt decomposition of $Q$ confirms the intuition that the sum has more than one term when $Q$ entangles the partitions and one term otherwise.